# Can somebody tell me why fVI is returning 0 every time when I am setting it to the first valid input the Scanner reads

Tags: java

In the method getHighestValue, why is fVI returning 0 every time? How do I get it to set it to the first valid input? I want to end up comparing it to each input that is entered to find the highest value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numCount;
    int numScores = 0;
    int values;
    int fVS; //fVS = First Valid Score

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter test scores between 50 and 109");

    numScores = getCount(input);
    fVS = getHighestValue(input);
    if (numScores == 0) {
        System.out.println("No scores read");
    } else {
        System.out.println(numScores + " " + fVS);
    }
}// ends main

//Counts the number of inputs
public static int getCount(Scanner input) {
    int values;
    int numberOfScores = 0;

    while (input.hasNextInt()) {
        values = input.nextInt();

        if (values > 49 && values < 110) {
            numberOfScores++;
        }
    } // ends while loop that scans for next int and counts each score input
    return numberOfScores;
}// ends getCount

//Finds the highest value
    public static int getHighestValue(Scanner input) {
        int fVI = 0;
        int value;
        int numberOfScores = 0;


        while (input.hasNextInt()) {
            value = input.nextInt();

            if (value > 49 && value < 110) {
                fVI = value;
                numberOfScores++;

            }

        } 
        return fVI;
    }// ends getHighestValue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have *one* scanner which `getCount()` will read integers from until there are no more left. Then `getHighestValue()` will also read integers from that scanner until there are none left.

But, and here's the rub, `getCount()` has *already* exhausted the scanner so there can be none left for `getHighestValue()`.

Your best bet is to probably read them into a collection of some description so they're available to *both* functions.

So have a new function that reads the scanner *once* and populates and returns (for example) a `Vector`, then pass that vector to the two functions for processing.